# AWS CodeBuild environment variables for versioning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Is there any type of AWS CodeBuild environment variables that can aid in stamping versioning information on build artifacts? . i.e. the equivalents of what Bamboo has such as `bamboo_buildNumber`.  Ideally I would want both build number and SCM number.

The docs talk about `CODEBUILD_x` variables for internal use, but I'm unable to find a listing of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reference to environment variables vended by CodeBuild for consumption is listed here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref.html#build-env-ref-env-vars

For build number related information, you can use CODEBUILD_BUILD_ID or CODEBUILD_BUILD_ARN. For the source related information, depending on how the build was triggered and what the input parameters to the build were (e.g. if you've specified source version while starting your build -- [reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_StartBuild.html)), you can additionally use CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION or CODEBUILD_SOURCE_REPO_URL environment variables.

CodeBuild documentation is not yet updated with the detailed information of these updated environment variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! btw .. is there a branch env variable ? Bamboo equivalent of bamboo_planRepository_branchName

Comment: CodeBuild primarily works with git commit hashes, but you can specify branch information while starting the build (instead of commit hash). CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION in this specific case will not resolve to the commit hash and will be name of the branch. Its exactly similar if you're trying to use tags instead of commit hashes/branches.

Answer (score 5):

Amazon has very recently added a BuildNumber environment variable.

According to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html

```
CODEBUILD_BUILD_NUMBER: The current build number for the project.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of environment variables, but in my experience they are not very reliable as they depend on how the build is triggered. The most useful ones seem to be:

```
echo "Region = ${AWS_REGION}"
echo "Account Id = $(echo $CODEBUILD_BUILD_ARN | cut -f5 -d ':')"
echo "Repo Name = $(echo $CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -f2 -d '/')"
echo "Commit Id = ${CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION}"
```

Which outputs:

```
Region = us-west-2
Account Id = 0123456789
Repo Name = my-app
Commit Id = a46218c9160f932f2a91748a449b3f9818964642
```